# c++ array syntax (function returns array)

Tags: c++, arrays

Why does this code require the '&' in array syntax?

```
int (&returnArray(int (&arr)[42]))[42]
{
  return arr;
}
```

When i declare it like this

```
int (returnArray(int arr[42]))[42]
{
  return arr;
}
```

i get

```
error C2090: function returns array
```

But isn't this an array it was returning in the first example? Was it some sort of a reference to array?

I know i can also pass an array to a function, where it will decay to a pointer

```
int returnInt(int arr[42])
{
  return arr[0];
}
```

or pass it by reference

```
int returnInt(int (&arr)[42])
{
  return arr[0];
}
```

But why can't i return an array the same way it can be passed?

Comment: @john I'd guess all C++ books worth their salt should mention array value semantics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't C++ support functions returning arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157439/why-doesnt-c-support-functions-returning-arrays)

Comment: i tried to edit the question to show that it's a little bit different from that one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int (&returnArray(int (&arr)[42]))[42]
```

The first `&` means this would return a *reference* to the array.

This is required by the standard :

> 8.3.5 Functions §6 -
>
> « **Functions shall not have a return type of type array** or function,
> although they may have a return type of type pointer or reference to
> such things. »

Comment: does it make sense because passing arrays as parameters **decays** into pointer ? thus implying the original type was always "array" and not pointer and as such cannot be expected to be returnable as a pointer type ? so this reflects the weirdness into why do we have decay at all.

Answer (score 3):

The first function is not returning an array, it's returning a *reference* to an array. Arrays cannot be returned by value in C++.

These topics are generally well covered in [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).