# Why ISO C++ forbids returning arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14

I don't see any logical reason. I mean you can easily overcome the requirement by using a structure containing an array member like this:

```
template <size_t n>
struct arr { int d[n]; };

auto fnReturningArray()
{
    return arr<3>{0, 1, 2};
};
```

Which will behave the exact same way as if the array is directly returned with the small difference that you should first access the structure member 'd' to use it. Also the standard itself have added similar functionality by the 'std::array' type. So it seems that it is implementation possible. Why then ISO C++ have forbidden this action? Maybe legacy code compatibility (but I can hardly believe this is the case as with the other new things added it is long gone, like for example the new meaning of the 'auto' keyword).

Comment: Because arrays cannot be copied.

Comment: Arrays are not copyable or assignable, so you cannot return or pass them by value. As to why that is, well, that would be a good question.

Comment: @Columbo But they became magically copyable when in struct.

Comment: Isn't that because arrays and pointers are effectively the same (and they are because of C compatibility)? So basically one should be able to use them interchangeably.

Comment: @Nikolay No, because they aren't, in either language.

Comment: @Nikolay: Who told you that "arrays and pointers are effectively the same"? They were wrong.

Comment: I mean, if a function has a pointer argument for example, you can't tell from within, what it is - an array or just a pointer.

Comment: @Nikolay Because it is  pointer, not an array. You can't know if a pointer points to an element in an array, but that is a different matter.

Comment: @Nikolay: Yes you can. It is a pointer. What you can't do is tell how large is the block of memory to which it points.

Comment: Yes guys, it looks like the "auto-convert array to the pointer to first element" rule which I meant by "equivalence" does not  prevent passing/returning arrays by value (so that's not the reason why it's not allowed in c++). Interesting duplicate discussion of the subject here (there is even an opinion that reason is heritage from "B" :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157439/why-doesnt-c-support-functions-returning-arrays

Comment: An array is not a modifiable lvalue in C++.   Which means an expression of `something = fnReturningArray()` is invalid, if the return value is actually an array type (e.g. of type `int [3]`).   This is inherited from C, which also prevents returning an array by value (unless wrapped in a `struct` type or, in C++, a `struct` or `class` type, as noted in the question)

Comment: In short, avoid naked arrays and use the C++ mechanisms that handle vectors properly.  You then will not be surprised by how badly native arrays are handled.

Comment: The actual correct way to handle this (esp given you have tagged question C++14) is not to use a struct that wraps a C array, but just to use `std::array`. There's almost no reason to ever use C arrays in C++.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the fact that the standard doesn't allow it, and the historical reasons that could explain it,  the issue is **syntactic**:

Imagine it would be permitted : how would you distinguish the naming of the whole array, vs the array address, vs a single element:

```
auto fnReturningArray()
{
    int a[3] = {0, 1, 2};
    return a;       // what is meant here ?  the address of the array ? or the whole array ?  
};
```

If you'd change the meaning of existing rules (such as tating that a would be the whole array), you would have huge problems with legacy code.

Comment: Presumably you would have a rule that states that you're returning `int[3]`, because that is the type of `a`. If the language allowed to return arrays, then this would make perfect sense. You're using a circular argument here.

Comment: That's easy: `a` is an array, so would mean you're returning an array. If you want a pointer to the first element, you'd write `&a[0]`. It's not how C++ works, but it would be a perfectly sensible language.

Comment: @hvd: But the fact that it's not how C++ works means it would be confusing/misleading/ambiguous syntax _in C++_ if added.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not saying that it would make sense to add it to C++ now, just that it would have made sense if that was how C++ (and perhaps even C) was designed from the start.

Comment: Clearly "int [3]". The most used type of arrays "int *" is created by implict cast. From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array). Check Array to pointer decay. If you want it to be a "int *" - you will cast like this "return (int *)a". Also as I mentioned above - 'C++ 11' already had broken compatibility with legacy code, written in the older standards so this is not an argument.

Comment: @hvd: With this I do not disagree

Comment: @Jako: It's not an "either/or" proposition; there are _degrees_ of broken compatibility and this would be a biggie.

Comment: I don't see a "broken compatibility issue". In C and C++, arrays decay only to pointers in specific, limited contexts. If C++ specified a new return type (arrays), that would be a new context for which C had no rules. The natural not-decay behavior works as expected there.

Comment: If it were legal to return the array, what could one do with it?  It would seem odd to allow `int foo[3],bar[3]; foo=funcReturningInt3Array();` when `foo=bar;` is forbidden.  If `int *moo; moo=funcReturningInt3Array();` were allowed, what would determine the lifetime of the array?

Comment: @supercat presumably, `foo =bar` would be allowed aswell and would copy the array. In your last example, I don't see anything that would warrant a different lifetime than with the today legal `moo = decltype(foo){1, 2, 3};`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: A general ability to treat arrays as values, decaying into pointers only when they were coerced into pointers or passed as variadic arguments, would be helpful, but I don't see any practical way of adding that to the language now.

Comment: @supercat One could use the return value to initialise an array variable for starters. All the other things would need additional changed rules, for obvious reasons. But then you'd end up with std::array with an implicit conversion to T*...

Answer (score 0):

The answer as I see it, is twofold:

1. Compatibility with C. C doesn't work this way. Why? No idea. C never was very logical to begin with in various aspects.
2. C++ prefers library features over language features. Seeing that C++98 was the first standard, and it mostly copied the basics from C (see point 1), this was corrected in the first major revision, C++11, which introduces the library type std::array, which, as a pure and simple library feature, solves all the abhorrent quirks that C-style arrays entail.

To summarise: even though it might make sense to have proper value semantics for arrays, it will never happen, because the apparent deficiency can be solved without making the language more complex than it already is. It is extremely difficult to get rid of legacy and backwards compatibility, so the current option of std::array is really what you want. Use it. It's simple. You'll like it. A lot.