# char [] as a return type in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

Is it possible to have a return type of a function be char[]

I know this works:

```
char* fun(char str[] {


blah blah

}
```

but I'm trying to do this:

```
char[] fun(char str[])
{

blah blah

}
```

and when I try to do that I get some syntax errors.

Comment: You cannot return an array in C.

Comment: No. It's not possible in C. You can't return *arrays*.

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't C++ support functions returning arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157439/why-doesnt-c-support-functions-returning-arrays)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return arrays in C.

Constraint of the function declarators:

> (C11, 6.7.6.3p1) "A function declarator shall not specify a return type that is a function type or an array type."