# Why returning array through pointer will not work in C++?? considering below code

Tags: c++11, pointers, stack, static-memory-allocation

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int add(int a, int b)
{
    int sum = a + b;
    return sum;
}

char* print()
{
    char arr[] = "Hello";
    char buffer[6];
    strcpy_s(buffer,arr);
    return buffer;
}

int main(){
    cout << add(2,3)<< endl;    // This prints "5"
    cout << print() <<endl;     // This prints junk!!!! 
}
```

1) add(2,3) print 5, how the value is ratained in this case considering print() function which returns pointer

2) Where 2 functions stored. Both will be stored in stack i guess, Why is print() function isnot printing "Hello" then

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your title and two bullets conflict. The memory would be stack because you aren't dynamically allocating memory.

Comment: My question is why in first case(cout statement) it prints 5. And in second cout it prints junk value. I was expecting "Hello"

Comment: Trying to return an array won't work as you think. Also this is a duplicate try going to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157439/why-doesnt-c-support-functions-returning-arrays .

Comment: @TimLayne Thank you, That helps :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't C++ support functions returning arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157439/why-doesnt-c-support-functions-returning-arrays)